# External Hard Drive not recognized after using it in Windows

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have a HFS external hard drive. I wanted to transfer a large file to my brother so I made him install the Paragon HFS+ program to be able to read it.

During the process something happened and the hard drive stopped working. Now I can't mount it in my Mac.

I can see that Windows recognizes the device but can't access it, while it is not recognizable in my Mac (neither in Disk Util or by running the diskutil command).

I don't know if there is a way to fix this problem.

Comment: Firstly, I would never trust Paragon's HFS+ on Windows as the same issue has happened to myself. Maybe try the solution from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291383/recover-files-after-paragon-hfs-corruption

Answer (score 1):

Can it still be recognized? Try First Aid or copying the files and erasing to ExFat so that you have access to large files on macOS and Windows.

Comment: It’s not recognizable.

Comment: I checked in System Information -> USB and I can see that it is recognizable there.

Comment: If you don't have any important files, then I would recommend formatting the USB drive as ExFat.